# what is the problem in this query it will delete all records of table !

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005

```
 Protected Sub GridView3_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView3.RowCommand
        For Each myRow As GridViewRow In GridView3.Rows
            'Find the checkbox
            Dim lab1 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label1"), Label)
            If e.CommandName = "Sumit" Then
                Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
                Dim con As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(constr)
                Try
                    Dim strSql As String = "DELETE * FROM hotels WHERE hotelid =" & lab1.Text

                    '------------"
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.CommandText = strSql
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Response.Write(ex.Message)
                Finally
                    cmd.Dispose()
                    con.Dispose()
                End Try
            End If
        Next
        GridView3.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

Comment: SQL injection hoooooooo!

Comment: You appear to be looping through all the rows and calling delete without checking anything row specific in your `if` condition. And use parameterised queries not string concatenation. And this seems to be a duplicate of [what was the problem in this Delete query ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017835/what-was-the-problem-in-this-delete-query) Edit your original question don't ask new questions on the same issue.

Comment: How to do that ... if i click on the dlete button of the row then that record got deleted ?

Comment: The code has lots of problems, but it seems that it will indeed delete all rows. Is that something you need, or something you want to avoid? Please add more context to the question...

Comment: CAn anybody redit to make this code working - if i click the delete button of row then the particular record got deleted not the all record from table.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use a stored procedure?  Your code would be more secure and a lot cleaner.  Passing a parameter to a stored procedure instead of a string to your DB is definitely the way to go here if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is this:

```
Protected Sub GridView3_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView3.RowCommand
    Dim myRow As GridViewRow = DirectCast((System.Web.UI.Control)(sender)).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)

    'Find the checkbox
    Dim lab1 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label1"), Label)

    If e.CommandName = "Sumit" Then
        Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim con As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(constr)
        Try
        Dim strSql As String = "DELETE FROM hotels WHERE hotelid =" & lab1.Text

        '------------"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = strSql
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
        Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        con.Dispose()
                End Try
            End If

            GridView3.DataBind()
        End Sub
```

The syntax may be off I'm not too familiar with VB.  As well it would be better to pass the ID of the hotel record in the `e.CommandArgument` thus you would not have to retrieve it from a label on the page.  It is deleting all your records because you are looping through all your rows in the grid view and deleting each record.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you think that will delete everything in the table, as I'm fairly certain it will not even execute. `DELETE` does not require any columns or `*` to be specified. It should just be `DELETE FROM hotels WHERE [etc, etc]`.

Also, you should seriously consider giving this article a read: [How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx). Especially "Step 3. Use Parameters with Dynamic SQL", which detail how you could change your code to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: +1 you just posted everything I wanted to say, and it was worded more concisely as well.  Bravo.

Comment: Correct, it will not execute.  The error message is *"Incorrect Syntax near *"*