# DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author = $userID;

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have this code in my functions.php

```
global $current_user;
$userid = $current_user->ID;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'listings',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'author' => $userid
);
$the_posts = get_posts ( $args ); // get the published posts for that author
$post_count = count($the_posts); // count the number of published posts for the author
$N = 2; // set number for max posts per user
if ($post_count > $N) {
    if (current_user_is('s2member_level1')) {   


       // This is where I want to delete from wp_post where post_author = $userID


    }
}
```

I'm not familiar enough with SQL query to figure out why its not working. I've tried

```
$wpdb = "DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author = $userID;"
```

and

```
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author = $userID;");
```

global $wpdb; is define earlier in my php file

Comment: Where is `$wpdb` defined?

Comment: What error message you have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the problem in this query it will delete all records of table !](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018131/what-is-the-problem-in-this-query-it-will-delete-all-records-of-table)

Comment: `$query = "DELETE FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_author='$current_user->ID'"; $id = $wpdb->query($query); return $id;`

Answer (score 1):

Delete should be written without the * character.

Answer (score 0):

the query should be like this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE ....;
```

in your case:

```
"DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author = $userID;"
```

Comment: This pretty much answers it. You can refer to http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp for more information and future reference as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose the value with '

Like so:

```
$wpdb = "DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author = '$userID';"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using  $user_ID = get_current_user_id();  after global $current_user;. or get_currentuserinfo() after declaring $current_user; and then get the current user id by $user_ID = $current_user->ID.  For more info of getting the current user logged in See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo